# Gibt es in manchen Dialekte lange Nasale als Phonem?

Tags: dialect, phonetics

Diese Frage ist praktisch ein Follow-Up auf [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/mitnehmen-with-2-syllables-or-3). Ich kenne mich einigermaßen mit Phonetik und Phonologie aus, und kann ein bisschen Finnisch (wo es Langkonsonanten gibt). Mit diesem Background kommt es mir (als Österreicher) so vor, als ob es in manchen Dialekten in Deutschland *lange* Formen der Nasale (/m/ und /n/) gäbe, die Phonemstatus haben; zB:

- [kɔm] -- *komm!*
- [(zi:) kɔm:] -- *(sie) kommen*

Oder:

- [(zi:) ge:n] -- *sie gehen*
- [(zi:) gɛ:n:] -- *sie gähnen*

Also in der "verschluckten" Form von unbetonten Endsilben "-men" und "-nen". Kann das jemand bestätigen, eventuell sogar mit Forschung dazu?

Oder bilde ich mir das ein, und solche Formen ergeben sich nur im Kontext, und unterscheiden sich in "isolierter" Form gar nicht?

Comment: Mir ist nicht ganz klar, was für dich der Unterschied wäre zwischen [kɔm.m̩] und [kɔ.m̩] in Bezug auf die *Wahrnehmung* durch die Sprecher. Der Sprecher macht sich beim Sprechen (und der Hörer beim Hören) ja keine Gedanken zur Silbenzahl der Wörter. Aus Kontext sowie aus der Länge des verschliffenen Schlussnasals wird klar, welche Wortform gemeint ist (nämlich Schriftform "kommen"). Wo sollte man da an Silbenzahlen denken?

Comment: Ich habe große Zweifel, ob in *echter* Alltagssprache ein Unterschied in der Länge des Schlusskonsonanten von "komm" und "kommen" besteht. Für meine Ohren sind beide gleich lang, wenn ich sie mir in einen Satz eingebettet gesprochen vorstelle. Mangels Bücherzugangs kann ich das aber momentan nicht nachschlagen. Bis dahin bleibt's daher erstmal eine nicht weiter fundierte Privatmeinung. ;)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wahrnehmung habe ich deshalb gesagt, weil ich die Schriftsprache weglassen wollte. Angenommen, zwei Dialektsprecher machen eine Art Ratespiel, bei denen Wörter _ohne_ Kontext gebraucht werden, und einer sagt [kom:]. Kann dann der Hörer eindeutig feststellen, ob "kommen", und nicht "komm!" gemeint war? Wenn ja, sollte er die Fähigkeit haben, /m/ von /m:/ mit Bedeutungsdifferenz zu unterscheiden, und wir hätten ein Phonem.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Aber in Bezug auf den Unterschied hast du eigentlich recht, die Silbenstruktur ist nicht relevant.

Comment: Hallo php, ach, so meintest du das: Ratespiel, ob ein Unterschied zwischen Komm! [kom] und kommen [kom:] gehört werden kann. Das wäre mal ein Experiment wert. Meine Vermutung wäre, dass es in der Praxis nicht (oder nur mit erheblicher Fehlerquote) zu hören ist. Auf der anderen Seite zeigt mir die Selbstbeobachtung als Sprecher, dass ich wenigstens gefühlt da schon einen Unterschied in der Aussprache mache: bei *kom:m* ist bei mir das m noch länger und es hat auch eine Tendenz, als zweites m mit Akzent gesprochen zu werden. Ich glaube aber wie gesagt nicht, dass man das dann auch hören kann.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ja, es gibt Dialekte mit langen Nasalen, aber die langen Nasale sind nicht verschluckte Nachsilben. Lange Nasale treten in den meisten Dialekten auf, die Langkonsonanten haben, also insbesondere in den hochalemannischen, allerdings mit Ausnahmen – so hat etwa da Zürichdeutsche sehr wohl Langkonsonanten, aber keine langen Sonoren.

Minimalpaare sind selten (z.B. altertümlich *dänne* /ˈtænːə/ ‘fort, weg’ vs. *däne* /ˈtænə/ ‘drüben’), aber *Name* /ˈnamə/ reimt sich nicht auf *Flamme* /ˈflamːə/, *Schine* /ˈʃɪnə/ ‘Schiene’ nicht auf *dinne* /ˈtɪnːə/ ‘drinnen’, *Channe* /ˈxanːə/ ‘Kanne’ nicht auf *cha’ne* /ˈxanə/ ‘kann ihn’, *immer* /ˈɪmːər/ nicht auf *gi’mer* /ˈkɪmər/ ‘gib mir’, *chum* /ˈxʊm/ ‘komm’ nicht auf *chrumm* /ˈxrʊmː/, etc. etc.

Lange Nasale aus verschliffenen Endsilben mögen phonetisch auftreten, aber ich kann mir schlecht vorstellen, dass sie in irgendeinem Dialekt ins phonologische System übernommen worden wären.

Comment: Das sind ein paar interessantere Beispiele, danke! Anscheinend habe ich mich zu sehr auf meine Endsilben konzentriert...

Answer (score 2):

Ich weiß nicht ob es hilft, aber das Phänomen der silbentragenden bzw. auch Phonemcharakter tragenden langen Schlussnasale kommt jedenfalls auch in der sogenannten Standardvariante der Aussprache vor, nicht etwa nur in Dialekten.

> Wennse wolln, könnse gehn! [Wenn Sie wollen, können Sie gehen.]
>
> Wose rechtham, hamse recht! [Wo Sie recht haben, haben Sie recht.]

Comment: Das war nun aber Berliner Dialekt.

Comment: @Janka Das klingt bei mir als Westfale nicht wesentlich anders.

Comment: @Uwe Meines Wissens zeigt das oben zitierte Beispiel auch nur die ganz alltägliche Assimilation von Lauten, nicht etwa eine dialektale Variante.

Comment: Das ist ein typisches Phänomen der Umgangssprache.

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe zufällig [dieses Paper](https://www.ipds.uni-kiel.de/kjk/pub_exx/kk1998_1/phonwor1.pdf) gefunden (K. Kohler: "The disappearance of words in connected speech"), das sich mit genau solchen Reduktionsphänomenen befasst die ich im Kopf hatte.  Es geht allerdings davon aus, dass es sich dabei eher um eine Art (rein phonetische) "Relexikalisierung" handelt:

> The disappearance of an independent phonetic word and the creation of a new lexical item

Beispielsweise nennt er die Reduktion zu [tsmm maːl] in *zum dreizehnten Mal*.

Ich schließe mich daher seiner Meinung an, dass man solche Phänomen auf Äußerungsebene betrachten muss:

> Word
> phonology has outlived itself. We have to look much more closely at the regularities of production
> and perception processes at the utterance level in actual speech communication, and this goal
> goes beyond the word as a phonetic unit and beyond the collection of phonetic variants lexica, [...]